# how to solve conflicts when installing mysql-python with anaconda

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I am using anaconda with python3.6 built in. I saw a python script with `import MySQLdb`. I have searched from google that I need to install mysql-python (I have installed mysql in my local PC). I type `conda install mysql-python`, but it seems that I meet a conflict as below. I have uninstalled python2.x from my PC, so I don't know what this message is saying.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8FZh.png)
Cound you please tell me how can I install mysql-python ??

when I type `python --version`, it gets:`Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)`.
when I type `conda install mysql-python`,it gets:
    Fetching package metadata ...........
    Solving package specifications: .

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mysql-python -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: When typing `python --version` what do you get? Also please post the error message as text and not as an image, as it is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comment~ I have adjusted my content.

Comment: The error means you have mysql-python installed for `python2.6`, which is in conflict with installing it for the 3.6 version. Do a `conda uninstall mysql-python`, then try installing again

Comment: yeah, it solved my problem, thanks a lot !